# Capturing named pattern inside another pattern

Tags: lua, lpeg

Consider the following lpeg pattern

```lua
pat = lpeg.C((lpeg.P " ")^0 * lpeg.C(lpeg.R "az") * lpeg.P ".")
lpeg.match(lpeg.Ct(pat), "    a.")
```

I would like to capture both the full substring and the letter only as two different named patterns, but I have some difficulties figuring out how this can be done. A named capture doesn't seem to survive an outer capture, e.g.

```lua
pat = lpeg.C((lpeg.P " ")^0 * lpeg.Cg(lpeg.C(lpeg.R "az"), "letter") * lpeg.P ".")
lpeg.match(lpeg.Ct(pat), "    a.")
```

only produces `{"    a."}`, without `letter`. At the same time I see no obvious way to unpack the two captured items into two separate groups without jumping though some very weird hoops (like capturing them into a named table and then using back captures to extract the individual items...

Comment: I don't know if this is also a weird hoop: `pat = lpeg.C((lpeg.P " ")^0 * lpeg.C(lpeg.R "az", "letter") * lpeg.P ".") / function(whole, letter) return { whole = whole, letter = letter } end`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to do what I need since it captures one table rather than two named captures. I need to be able to refer to the the captured values using  Cb etc.

Comment: It's not possible to nest named captures in LPeg. Based on my personal experience, LPeg's back capture (`Cb`) can only be used for some simple scenarios.

Comment: Why do you need to make a back reference? If you want to build complexer patterns, you could rebuild the same string if you capture what came before and what comes after and use three `Cb`.